# ¿Cómo pasar valores entre componentes Vue hermanos sin usar 'params'?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Actualmente cuento con 2 componentes:

- Proyectos.vue
- Reuniones.vue

Donde:

- **Proyectos**: es el componente que muestro de inicio donde se muestra el
  listado de proyectos.
- **Reuniones**: es el componente donde se muestra el listado de reuniones
  de un proyecto.

En el componente `Proyectos` hago una solicitud `GET` la cual me retorna un arreglo de objetos, es decir proyectos. Este listado de proyectos lo lleno en una tabla.

**Estructura objeto Proyecto:**

```
    {
        objetivo:"", 
        fecha: "",
        reuniones: [
        {
            titulo: "",
            fecha: ""
        },
        {
            titulo: "",
            fecha: ""
       }]
   }
```

Por cada renglón de tabla tengo un objeto javascript `proyecto` el cual deseo enviar al componente `Reuniones` al hacer clic en un botón. Una vez en el componente Reuniones haré ciertas acciones con ese objeto.

[image: Flujo esperado]

### Decisión de no utilizar params

Estoy buscando la forma de **no** tener que mandar el `Id` por la url y tener que hacer un nuevo get del objeto. Quiero utilizar el objeto con el que ya cuento desde el componente `Proyectos`.

### Intento de uso de eventos

Traté de utilizar eventos mediante `$emit` y `$on` pero como el componente `Reuniones` todavía no está cargado no puede escuchar del evento que envío desde el componente `Proyectos`.

**Proyectos.vue**:

```
proyectoSeleccionado (proyecto) {
    // Emito un evento con el objeto proyecto
    this.$root.$emit('enviar', proyecto)
    // Mando llamar la ruta 'reuniones', misma que cargar el controlador reuniones
    this.$router.push('reuniones')
}
```

**Reuniones**

```
this.$root.$on('enviar', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

---

En comportamiento que estoy buscando es poder utilizar un objeto entre componentes.

Answer (score 2):

si desea tener una comunicación con un componente a otro puede utiliza el siguiente código

```
<script>
    
    import Hijo from "../components/reuniones.vue";
    export default {
        components: {
            Hijo,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                is_enviar: false,
                validacion: [],
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            this.anadir_registro();
        },
        methods: {
            anadir_registro() {
                //ejecuta la funcion consulta en  reuniones
                this.$refs.Hijo.consulta();
            },
          }
    }
    </script>
    
 <template>

        <reuniones v-bind:proyecto_id=proyecto_id  ref="Hijo"></reuniones>
</template>
```

fin del archivo
componerte de reunió desde este componente se une con proyecto
desde este punto se realiza la consulta

```
<script>
//import Vue from "vue";

export default {
    computed: {

        /*
        sheetHijo: {
            get() {
                alert(this.proyecto_id)
                return this.proyecto_id;
            },
            set(proyecto_id) {
                this.$emit("proyecto_id");
            }

        }
        */
    },
    components: {
    },
    props: ["proyecto_id", "is_editar"],
    data() {
        return {
            is_enviar: false,
            validacion: [],
            proyecto_id_reunion: this.proyecto_id,

        };
    },
    mounted() {

        this.consulta();
        alert(proyecto_id)
        

    }
    ,
    methods: {
        consulta(){
            alert(proyecto_id)

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si haces un cambio de ruta, se pierde el estado, a menos que uses Vuex para almacenar ese objeto en el store y poder compartirlo..

Pero, si el componente que recibe el objeto wrappea el componente reuniones y no es destruido, podés pasarlo como prop o instalar plugin vue-events que es más fácil de entender que los eventos que vienen por defecto en Vue...

Comment: Hola. No entiendo bien esta parte: "si el componente que recibe el objeto wrappea el componente reuniones y no es destruido".

Comment: el componente que recibe el objeto, se mantiene cuando cambias a la ruta reuniones?

Comment: No, porqué como el componente todavía no está cargado. El $on en Reuniones no puede escuchar el $emit que hago desde Proyectos.vue.

Comment: Yo lo que hago,  es , usando vue-events,( cuando no quiero usar Vuex)

Comment: ¿Pero como hacer para escuchar el evento en otro componente que aun no está cargado?

Comment: Disculpas, se me envio el mensaje incompleto, en el mounted del evento que no esta cargado, lanzo el evento 
this.$events.fire('get-data-from-other-component')

el componentn que escuche y mantenga el objeto en el cambio de ruta (puede ser el comp anterior si no se destruyo u otro componente fijo como navbar ) lanza otro evento con el objeto

'get-data-from-other-component' () { this.$events.fire('send-object', object) }

es medio rebuscado pero si no queres usar Vuex no te queda otra

Comment: si podes para que te ayude mejor subilo a un plunker